# Edit a bound DataTable in Visual Studio GUI Dsigner?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am extremely new to c# and WinForms, so I apologize in advance if this is something trivial.

With my mouse only, I created a form in the Visual Studio Designer and added a DataGridView to it. Then via code, I created a DataTable, added a few columns, added a bunch of generated rows, and bound it to the DataGridView with the following command:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

The program works just fine. However, in the Designer I see the DataGridView empty, and cant make any column related changes such as changing a column color, changing its size, etc.

Note that **I DO** know the column names and types in advance. It is only the data itself which is dynamic and generated on the fly.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm know for sure you can change make your column related  change in the backend code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

You would need to iterate trough your grid and change every row/columns/cell properties.

```
`Dim test As New DataGrid 
 test.Columns(0).ItemStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.AliceBlue`
```

This is vb code, but it would be pretty much the same thing in every language.

Otherwise, to use the GUI you can go in the properties->style

Exemple :

http://imageshack.com/a/img837/4024/hvda.png

Comment: I am well aware I can make any changes via code, but the whole point of the question was being able to edit my table via the GUI.